# Retrieve correct file URI in Java

Tags: java, scala, url, uri

The .toString method of java.net.URI does not encode local file URLs correctly.

```
scala> new java.io.File("/tmp/d.jpg").toURI.toString
res0: String = file:/tmp/d.jpg
```

Why does the URI not generate?

```
file:///tmp/d.jpg
```

**Edit**
I discovered this while passing a file on to the shell on Linux, eventually executing convert (ImageMagick), which cannot handle the single slash version, file:/tmp/d.jpg. It works when I pass an http URI, which is toStringed correctly by java.net.URI. I guess convert does not follow the RFC strictly.

Comment: I think the question is answered in the link - can I acknowledge Jens, or should I answer the question myself an accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link added to the original post, answers my question.

In order to be able to pass URIs to the shell (convert), I will be doing this (notice, it is Scala code):

  `private def getSourceForShell(source: URI): String = {
    if (source.getScheme == "file") {
        "file://" + source.toString
        } else {
            source.toString
        }
  }`

I guess it is a work around for convert, which does not support the single slash (no authority) URI format.